# A "recomendations" Table Structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

You know how people look for movies or TVshows that are similar or recommended?

http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/devil-may-cry

see how at the bottom it shares recommended animes, and they are interlinked to each other as recommendations so if you link A -to- B  on B you can see A too, and 
A -to- B 
B -to- C
C -not- A

my question is how are theses entries best handled?

Listings_Table

- list_id
- list_title
- list_content

Recommends_Table

- list_id_A
- list_id_B

though this method would cause duplicates a lot i think, queries would be a bit messy too I think. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a relatively simple recommendation engine.  It would work fine for a small dataset where you are manually assigning the recommendations, where A points to B and B points to C, however its not a very scalable approach.  Once you hit any more than a trivial amount of products it becomes too unwieldy to maintain (in my opinion).

What you may find serves you better is to use something a little more sophisticated.  Take a look at how people use something like Google's Prediction api (http://code.google.com/apis/predict/docs/samples.html#demos) to do just this very sort of prediction.  In that case you wouldn't be storing the actual linkage, but rather what users liked what, and then looking at that information to build your recommendations.

While the Prediction API isn't a perfect solution for all people, it will give you a pretty easy way to build out a recommendations portion of your site without having to learn machine learning techniques in depth.

As for your table structure above, you wouldn't need to duplicate data if you DID do it like that.  Instead what I would suggest is that you look for the element you're on in both of the columns in the recommends_table.

For example, if you have the following records in "Recommendations_table"

```
list_id_A, list_id_B
1, 2
9, 12
2, 3
```

You could grab everything related to "2" by using a query that unions, such as:

```
select list_id_A from recommendations_table where list_id_B = 2
union
select list_id_B from recommendations_table where list_id_A = 2
```

Additionally you could add some more sql to make sure you only return unique results.  But in the end, how do you populate that information, as that is likely to make more of a difference than anything.

If you would to go a step further and use a different technology such as a nosql data store like Cassandra, you could have a column family called recommendations, and your key would be the movie you are  viewing.  Then the subsequent column names would be the recommended movie ids.  In that  case you would have something like this for the structure:

```
Key, columns.....
Movie A, 4, 5, 67,1, 9,3
Movie B, 3, 4, 1
```

In that case you would pull all the column names for a particular key and that would be your recommendation list.

All of this is really kind of academic without knowing how you plan to populate the data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I appreciate it. If it would help I plan on making it almost exactly like the site I linked to: http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/devil-may-cry

Except for movies, and instead of notes on the recommendation, it will be image, title and brief details only.

Would MySQL be able to handle things if it was set in the Cassandra option structure? And yes I would like a proper scaling method as it will get quite large.

Thanks again

Comment: When I suggest something like Cassandra, I do so not in thinking that it is a replacement for SQL necessarily.  Instead, it would give you a place to look up the ids for the things you want to present inside your recommendations.  So you would use something like Cass to grab ids, and then store the relational info in SQL, and look up the SQL related info based on the ids you pulled out of your alternative datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any dublicates if (list_id_A, list_id_B) is a primary key of Recommends_Table. Also, if you want the links to be two-way, then when inserting a new row into Recommends_Table, say (A, B), you'll have to also insert (B, A). Triggers would help in this case.

Alternatively, you could insert only (A, B) or only (B, A) and use the query that dmcnelis suggested:

```
select list_id_A from recommendations_table where list_id_B = 2
union
select list_id_B from recommendations_table where list_id_A = 2
```

I think the alternative solution is better, because you'll have less data to store at the Recommends_Table. But, in this case, if you already have a (A, B) row in the table, then it would be useless to also insert a (B, A). In order to prevent this, you can use triggers, again.